# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when call rest API

Tags: rest-api, wp-api

I am using ReactJs with WordPress. WordPress running on localhost `8888` port and React app running on `3000` port. When I change the WordPress site URL (from settings->general) to `localhost:300` then I am getting the following error,

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:8888/bolb/wp-json/wp/v2/categories' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

It's not working on the postman too. But, it's okay if I use the same URL (http://localhost:8888/bolb) as the site URL.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just write this on your function.php

```
add_filter( 'allowed_http_origin', '__return_true' );
```